# Why doesn't kubectl bash completion work on macOS/OS X?

Tags: bash, kubernetes, homebrew, bash-completion, kubectl

I followed the instructions for installing Bash completion as given by `kubectl completion -h`:

1. I installed `bash-completion` via Homebrew
2. In my `~/.bashrc`, I first source `bash-completion` then output from the completion kubectl subcommand:

   - `source $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion`
   - `source <(kubectl completion bash)`

With these in place, I start up a new shell but the completion doesn't work. How do I get it working?

Answer (score 10):

Once `bash-completion` is installed by Homebrew, it appears that its completions 
need to reside in `$(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion.d`. There you'll find a lot of other completions that come bundled. To add the completion for kubectl:

```
$ kubectl completion bash > $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion.d/kubectl
```

That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

I the answer form Ahmet B, the fix says to add the following to your .bashrc file:

```
export BASH_COMPLETION_COMPAT_DIR="/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d"
[[ -r "/usr/local/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh" ]] && . "/usr/local/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh"
```

However, the install of completions 2:

```
brew install bash-completion@2
```

finishes with a message to add the export line if you would LIKE TO USE V1 completions. Removing that export enabled kubectl completion for me.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers didn't work for me, but I found out [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/37#issuecomment-458857274) solution:

```
source /dev/stdin <<<"$(kubectl completion bash)"
```

Comment: I tried this on bash 3.2 with macOS 11.6, and it didn't work - the 'source from stdin' part works with 3.2, but I believe the kubectl-generated bash script (from parenthesised part) [now requires](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/included/optional-kubectl-configs-bash-mac/) bash 4.2+ and bash-completion v2.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach:

**Install bash and bash-completion**

```sh
brew install bash bash-completion
```

**Set Terminal to use bash**

`Preferences` > `General` > `Shell open with: Command (complete path)`:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/bash
```

**Check the location bash-completion has been installed to**

```sh
brew info bash-completion
```

> Bash completion has been installed to:
> /opt/homebrew/etc/bash_completion.d

**Edit ~/.bashrc**

```
alias k="kubectl"
complete -F __start_kubectl k
source /opt/homebrew/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh
source <(kubectl completion bash)
```

**Reload Terminal and verify that the completion works**

```sh
~$ k <TAB>
```

> alpha          auth           cordon         diff           get            patch          run            version
> annotate       autoscale      cp   ...

**Environment**

- macOS Monterey 12.2.1
- Homebrew 3.3.15
- GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (aarch64-apple-darwin21.1.0)
- bash-completion: stable 1.3 (bottled)
- kubectl v1.23.3

Comment: This does work, rest everything seems outdated.

Answer (score 0):

See the "On macOS, using bash" section of kubectl documentation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#on-macos-using-bash 
 I recently contributed those so they should be up to date. If not, please send a pull request to fix it.

Also: https://blog.fabric8.io/enable-bash-completion-for-kubernetes-with-kubectl-506bc89fe79e

Answer (score 0):

1. After `brew install bash-completion`, to actually enable bash completions, you need to:

   ```sh
   source /usr/local/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh
   ```

   Add that line to you `bashrc`.
2. Then you can:

   ```sh
   source <(kubectl completion bash)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

managed to get it working in MacOS 12.5 by fixing some file permissions. using bash 5.1.16
in terminal type:

```
brew install bash
echo $BASH_VERSION
5.1.16(1)-release

chsh -s /opt/homebrew/Cellar/bash/5.1.16/bin/bash
brew install bash-completion@2
ls -la /opt/homebrew/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh

lrwxr-xr-x  1 myuser  admin  68 Aug  2 17:19 /opt/homebrew/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh -> ../../Cellar/bash-completion@2/2.11/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh
```

but the symbolic link target! had no executable flag so:

```
chmod +x /opt/homebrew/Cellar/bash-completion\@2/2.11/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh
```

then edit your `~/.bash_profile` :

```
if [[ -r "/opt/homebrew/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh" ]]; then 
source /opt/homebrew/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh
echo "installed bash auto completions"
else
echo "Huston we have an auto compl problem"
fi

source <(kubectl completion bash)
alias k=kubectl
```